# AWS Lambda, Python : Get Instances with launch tme for sorting syntax error, Error in Comparing tags

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am working on an AWS Lambda code where I want to get all instances with a specific Value, sort them in reverse order to remove the oldest instance, and pass commands to the remaining instances.

Here are the 2 issues I am facing :
1) As soon as I remove **`print "Tag value is %s"%(tag['Value'])`** from the code part, I am getting null response for perfectly working code otherwise.

2) As I am adding the instances to a list, I am not able to sort them with LaunchTime attribute, is there any alternate way?

Code :

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    reservations = boto3.client('ec2').describe_instances()['Reservations']
    instances_list = []
    process_instance_list = []
    command = 'crontab -r'
    ssm = boto3.client('ssm')
    for res in reservations:
      instances = res['Instances']
      for inst in res['Instances']:
        for tag in inst['Tags']:
            print("Tag value is {}".format(tag['Value']))
//Below if loop doesn't work if above printout is removed. 
            if tag['Value']=='Ubuntu_Magento':
               print("{} {} {}".format(tag['Value'], inst['InstanceId'], inst['LaunchTime']))
               instances_list.append(inst)

// Below line gives syntax error, even though I have used LaunchTime param above    
    instances_list.sort(key=lambda x: x['LaunchTime'] reverse=False)
    non_processed_id=instances_list[0]['InstanceId']

    for val in instances_list:
        if val['InstanceId'] != non_processed_id['InstanceId']:
          ssmresponse = ssm.send_command(InstanceIds=[val['InstanceId']], DocumentName='AWS-RunShellScript', Parameters= { 'commands': [command]})
```

Comment: Any reason you are using python 2.7 and not 3.6 in the Lambda code?

Comment: @balderman : Changed the runtime to Python3.6 in AWS, no effect.

Comment: Can you please 1) Fix the code indentation 2) Explain where you get a null response.

Comment: About `instances_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.inst['LaunchTime'] reverse=False)`. Does the entry in instances_list contains a property named `inst`. What is the datatype of the entry? I think it is a dict and therefore it has no `inst` property

Comment: @balderman : Fixed the indentation, added in code where it's failing. I removed the x.inst, as I was just trying out what can work. As You can see in the first part of code, where I am iterating through EC2 instances, I am printing the launch time property and it's working when the print statement is present. But it's not working when I want to iterate the Instances object as a list and set get it's LaunchTime property.

Comment: I can see in the code that you are still calling print in a way that can work only in python 2.x. Are you sure you changed the runtime to 3.6. The code is not indented: `for inst in res['Instances']:  for tag in inst['Tags']` Please upload a 'clean' version of the code.

Comment: @balderman : My Bad, I had directly changed it in AWS Lambda Web Mangement Console's inline editor. Copied the code from there to here now. :-) Thank you. :-)

Comment: `for tag in inst['Tags']:
 print("Tag value is %s"%(tag['Value']))`  is not a valid python code

Comment: @balderman : And again ur right, seems like AWS didn't change the runtime immediately. It did now, and the code started failing. Fixed the print outs with format statement, still the same issues though. Thank you. :-)

Comment: Run the code from your computer and debug it step by step.